# add a Read instance to Path to Path package

Tags: haskell, parsec

I like the Path package and use it often. The main inconvenience for me is the lack of a Read instance for Path. It is obvious that one would require 4 different instances like

```
instance Read (Path Rel File) where
instance Read (Path Rel Dir) where
instance Read (Path Abs Dir) where
instance Read (Path Abs File) where
```

but I cannot see how to define the `readsPrec` function. It would need a parser function for filepath. 
I guess that somebody has already written a parser for file path and I understand that a lot of special cases must be considered. I cannot find such a function. Where should I look?

Comment: There are [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.6.1/docs/Path.html#v:parseAbsDir) in `path` to parse paths.

Comment: I saw these functions and I use them, but I do not see how to construct a Read instance with them. Unfortunately, the readsPrec function has a different type.

Comment: Sure, the definition is not as trivial as `readsPrec = parseAbsDir` but it is still quite simple. If you have tried to implement `Read` with these functions but did not succeed, include your attempts and any relevant errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I exploit the fact, that the show function of Path produces a String

```
instance Show (Path b t) where
  show = show . toFilePath
```

Therefore, the read can first read the string and then analyze the string:

```
instance Read (Path Abs Dir) where
   readsPrec i r =   
        maybe []  (\res -> [(Path res, rem1)] ) $ Path.parseAbsDir x
        where  [(x ::String , rem1)] = readsPrec i r
```

I do not like the approach very much and had prefered a parser for a file path not relying on the ".." around the value.

Any suggestions how this can be improved?